# Skip running tests from external Unlocked package

Tags: unit-test, unlocked-package

We use [`Nebula Logger`](https://github.com/jongpie/NebulaLogger) as an unlocked package. During a CI job we create a scratch org and run all local tests:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run --codecoverage --resultformat human --wait 60 --testlevel RunLocalTests
```

This also launches unit tests from the Nebula Logger. Is it possible to skip those tests? We don't want to waste time on running the tests from an external package.